# Add VendorCreditApply to VendorCreditApplyList Suitetalk

Tags: c#, netsuite

I don't know why I get this error when trying to update `VendorCredit` with `VendorCreditApplyList`

```
var creditObj = new List<VendorCredit>(searchResultCredit.recordList.Cast<VendorCredit>()).FirstOrDefault();
VendorCreditApplyList vCreditApplyList = new VendorCreditApplyList();
VendorCreditApply[] vCreditApplyArray = new VendorCreditApply[creditObj.applyList.apply.Length + 1];

var searchResultBill = _service.search(transactionsSearchBill);
if (searchResultCredit.status.isSuccess)
{
   var billObj = new List<VendorBill>(searchResultBill.recordList.Cast<VendorBill>()).FirstOrDefault();

   for(int i = 0; i < creditObj.applyList.apply.Length; i ++)
   {
      vCreditApplyArray[i] = creditObj.applyList.apply[i];
   }

   vCreditApplyArray[creditObj.applyList.apply.Length] = new VendorCreditApply()
      {
         amount = (double)creditAmount,
         amountSpecified = true,
         apply = true,
         applySpecified = true,
         applyDate = DateTime.Now,
         applyDateSpecified = true,
         currency = billObj.currencyName,
         doc = Convert.ToInt64(billObj.internalId),
         docSpecified = true,
         due = billObj.userTotal,
         dueSpecified = true,
         line = 0,
         lineSpecified = true,
         refNum = null,
         total = billObj.userTotal,
         totalSpecified = true,
         type = "Bill"
      };

}
vCreditApplyList.apply = vCreditApplyArray;
creditObj.applyList = vCreditApplyList;              
WriteResponse writeRes = _service.update(creditObj);

return writeRes.status;
```

I got error :

> "All lines of sublist `applyList` have to be specified when replace All is requested"

I don't really understand it ...

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the `creditObj.applyList` property to `vCreditApplyList`. That is an empty list because you don't do anything with it after declaring it. You have created `vCreditApplyArray` by copying the sublist and adding a new element, but you haven't updated `vCreditApplyList` with it.

Comment: Hi Klitos, thanks for your comment, I'm sorry that I was missed while copying the code >.<. I have just updated my code, and still get that error.

Answer (score 1):

I found out the answer.

Because VendorCredit is a Keyed Sublist, so I just need to add replaceAll = false, then submit only the record that I have to add.

Comment: Glad you've solved it. However, I'm still not sure why you were getting the error because, according to the Platform Guide, you should be able to update keyed sublists with replaceAll = true.

Comment: I've follow the newest document from Netsuite, they updated the keyed sublist https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N3441570.html